# Definition of closed surface/manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

This question might appear silly,

I was reading on wikipedia that a closed surface (or manifold in general) is a surface without a boundary, I'd like to elaborate a bit on such definition.

Assuming we have a smooth manifold $\mathcal{S}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can we say that $\mathcal{S}$ is closed if every $p \in \mathcal{S}$ is an interior point in $\mathcal{S}$ w.r.t. the topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The interval $[0,1]\subset\Bbb R$ should certainly not be considered closed (or unbounded). However, every point is an interior point in the subspace topology. On the other hand, a circle $S^1\subset\Bbb R^2$ is a closed manifold but it has no interior points when considered as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's more to a closed manifold than just being a manifold without boundary.

Your proposal would allow an entire line in the plane. But a line is not compact as a topological space, so it's not a "[closed manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold)".

Comment: Is then the combination of my proposal + compactness the correct one?